# Constructor to assign instance name from super constant when adding instance in Flash IDE?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a library object (`SomethingMC`) which extends a custom class (`Something`). `Something`, in turn, extends `MovieClip`.

If adding `SomethingMC` to the stage within Flash CS3 IDE, is it possible for it's super class (`Something`) to assign an instance name from a class constant (`Something.THE_CONSTANT`)?

```
package
{
  import flash.display.MovieClip;
  import flash.events.Event;

  public class Something extends MovieClip
  {
    public static const THE_CONSTANT:String = 'anInsanceName';

    public function Something():void
    {
      addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, assignInstanceName);
    }

    protected function assignInstanceName(event:Event):void
    {
      this.name = THE_CONSTANT;
    }
  }
}
```

The above does not work. It throws `Error #2078: The name property of a Timeline-placed object cannot be modified.` if the instance is assigned a name in the IDE, and it just doesn't work if no name is assigned in the IDE.

I'm afraid the answer is no...

Comment: yip. as it says ... if it was possible you will lose the reference in the timeline.

Comment: i would not make any sense though because if you'd add a second instance of this class there both would share the same instance-name.

Comment: Haha yes that's a good point!

Comment: Granted, though, in my situation, there would have only been one instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, but I like the idea.  It would certainly be nice to be able to do this rather than having to name each key-framed instance of a DisplayObject you wish to target via it's instance name.